# c++ beginner needs help inputing & outputing data! what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++

so this code is for a car garage, filling info of the accepted cars to be repaired everyday.
and print the result for each car in a line.

i have two problems with my code.
first is, starting the second time the "do...while... " loop runs, i cant have an input for "enter car name"
second is the final output, i want it in straight neat lines
but can't !

I'll be so grateful if someone gives me the edited and fixed version of my code!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int D; //are you done?
int main()
{
    int i = 0; //counting cars
    string cars[10][7] = {};
    string C = cars[i][1]; //car name
    string N = cars[i][2]; //owner name
    string Y = cars[i][3]; //car production year
    string R = cars[i][4]; //car color
    string K = cars[i][5]; //car life in km
    string M = cars[i][6]; //car problem
    string H = cars[i][7]; //time of arrival

    do {
        i++;
        cout << endl;
        cout << " enter car name ";
        getline(cin, cars[i][1]);
        cout << endl;
        cout << " enter owner name ";
        getline(cin, cars[i][2]);
        cout << endl;
        cout << " enter production year ";
        getline(cin, cars[i][3]);
        cout << endl;
        cout << " enter car color ";
        getline(cin, cars[i][4]);
        cout << endl;
        cout << " enter car life in km ";
        getline(cin, cars[i][5]);
        cout << endl;
        cout << " enter car problem ";
        getline(cin, cars[i][6]);
        cout << endl;
        cout << " enter time of arrival ";
        getline(cin, cars[i][7]);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "this was car :" << i << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "type '1' to continue. type '2' if you are done." << endl;
        cin >> D;
    } while (D == 1);

    cout << endl << "ended ! here is today's list of cars :";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; cout << "\t" << cars[i][j] && j++);
        {
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string H=cars[i][7] ; //time of arrival` is out of bounds. Indices are from 0 to size-1.

Comment: use inline "\n" or "\t" in your lines. \n is new line. \t is tab.

Comment: You should also read [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: With `string C=cars[i][1] ; //car name` you will make a copy of the *empty* string `cars[0][1]`. Then you never use this variable `C` again (or the other variables beyond `i` and `cars`) again. What use is those unused variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: this was actually my first time coding. After doing 2 other ones. then came back to edit this one and changed somethings. so these variables were used in the previous version and i couldn't delete them cause i was getting errors. so if it isn't broken, why fix it :)))     of course i have to learn more...@Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed code you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>


int main( )
{
    std::size_t idx { }; // counting cars
    constexpr std::size_t maxCarCount { 20 };
    constexpr std::size_t carAttributesCount { 7 };
    std::array< std::array<std::string, carAttributesCount>, maxCarCount > cars { };

    char isDone { }; // are you done?

    do
    {
        std::cout << "\n enter car name: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, cars[idx][0] );
        std::cout << "\n enter owner name: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, cars[idx][1] );
        std::cout << "\n enter production year: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, cars[idx][2] );
        std::cout << "\n enter car color: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, cars[idx][3] );
        std::cout << "\n enter car life in km: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, cars[idx][4] );
        std::cout << "\n enter car problem: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, cars[idx][5] );
        std::cout << "\n enter time of arrival: ";
        std::getline( std::cin, cars[idx][6] );
        std::cout << "\nThis was car #" << idx + 1 << '\n';

        std::cout << "\nType '1' to continue, type '2' if you are done.\n";
        std::cin >> isDone;
        std::cin.ignore( ); // this solves one of your issues

        ++idx;

    } while ( isDone == '1' );

    std::cout << "\nEnded! Here is today's list of cars:\n\n";

    for ( std::size_t carIdx { }; carIdx < idx; ++carIdx )
    {
        for ( std::size_t carAttributeIdx { }; carAttributeIdx < carAttributesCount; ++carAttributeIdx )
        {
            std::cout << "\t" << cars[carIdx][carAttributeIdx];
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if the info for more than 20 cars is entered then the `cars` will overflow and cause undefined behavior. It has space for only 20 cars. If you want to remove this limitation then switch to `std::vector< std::vetor<std::string> > cars( 20, std::vector<std::string>(7) );`.

Sample input/output:

```
 enter car name: 911

 enter owner name: John

 enter production year: 1999

 enter car color: Yellow

 enter car life in km: 3100

 enter car problem: broken

 enter time of arrival: 12:06

This was car #0

Type '1' to continue, type '2' if you are done.
1

 enter car name: 718

 enter owner name: Kate

 enter production year: 2021

 enter car color: Red

 enter car life in km: 465

 enter car problem: broken headlight

 enter time of arrival: 13:45

This was car #1

Type '1' to continue, type '2' if you are done.
2

Ended! Here is today's list of cars:

        911     John    1999    Yellow  3100    broken  12:06
        718     Kate    2021    Red     465     broken headlight        13:45
```